# Modifying a pointer pointer field from a method

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to modify a bool field in a method. The method accepts a pointer pointer bool, but can't seem to figure it out how to do this correctly.

This is a basic example of something similar I want to do:

```
class WarningManager {
    bool seenWarningA; 

    void updateWarnings() {
        pushWarning(&seenWarningA)
    }

    void pushWarning(bool ** warning) {
        **warning = true;
    }
}
```

This code example errors (sending bool* but needs to be bool**) and I've tried other ways with no luck. Can't find any online examples but maybe I'm searching for the wrong terms. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Why do you think you need to use pointers here?

Comment: What do you think `warning` points to? The address of `seenWarningA`? *Where do you think that address is stored?*

Comment: @NeilButterworth If you can think of a better way of doing this without pointers, I would also be interested. Could do ref pointers?

Comment: I see no need for double-indirection in this code at all. At-most single indirection is suitable (or just a regular reference and no pointers). I can only assume `pushWarning` is doing something monumental an unseen; otherwise this is pointless and `updateWarnings` would simply `seenWarningsA = true;` would be done.

Comment: I can't provide a better way because you have not really explained fully what you are trying to do. Whatever it is, the chances of it requiring a pointer-to-pointer are pretty minimal.

Comment: _The code example errors_ it would be best to [edit] your question to include the full compiler error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a class, no parameters are required.

```
class WarningManager {
bool seenWarningA; 

void updateWarnings() {
    pushWarning()
}

void pushWarning() {
    seenWarningA = true;
}
}
```

Using references rather than pointers is more elegant.

```
class WarningManager {
bool seenWarningA; 

void updateWarnings() {
    pushWarning(seenWarningA)
}

void pushWarning(bool & warning) {
    warning = true;
}
}
```

If you want to use pointers, the & operator just gives single pointer rather than a double point:

```
class WarningManager {
bool seenWarningA; 

void updateWarnings() {
    pushWarning(&seenWarningA)
}

void pushWarning(bool * warning) {
    *warning = true;
}
}
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise the bottom example is all I need. I got confused in something I read. Thanks.

Comment: The bottom example isn't what you need, the second example is what you need. Notice when you're using pointers how confusing code becomes, and it's easy to mis-write it. That never happens with references, so it's far better to just use those (plus you wouldn't need to check for `nullptr` before use)

Comment: Yes, I totally agree Tas. I don't use pointers until I need to.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be trying to pass an argument of bool* into a function that takes bool**.  Remove one of the layers of indirection from the parameter list, or add one to the value you're passing in.  Either should work.

Answer (score 1):

Two mistakes:

First- your declaration of `pushWarning` is with parameter of type `bool**`, and you are trying to send `bool*`.

Second- you can simply use reference:

```
using namespace std;

class WarningManager {
public:
    bool seenWarningA;

    void updateWarnings() {
        pushWarning(seenWarningA);
    }

    void pushWarning(bool &warning) { // You can simply use refference instead of pointer to pointer, or pointer at all..
        warning = true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    WarningManager w;
    w.seenWarningA = false;
    w.updateWarnings();
    cout << w.seenWarningA; // Prints 1

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Tas I took the name before it been edited, so I didn't had much attention to class's name, but you right. And I prefer to use `using namespace std`, I just forgot to put it here :)